# Find the side view and simple 3d

Tags: geometry, three-dimensional

[image]

> Find the side view and simple 3d associated with these views.It is given that there are no hidden lines (lines which are not visible from the side or top view).

Comment: You can edit posts with the "edit" button under the tags. I've deleted your old post for you - next time, just edit it rather than posting a new one.

Comment: Does this figure have to be closed? (Can it have lines)

Comment: Perhaps the puzzle statement could mention whether the object is transparent or opaque

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As the top view has 90° symmetry, 
a 90° side view...

> ...can look exactly the same as the front view.

A 45° side view can be more interesting, ...

> ...showing an almost-elliptical profile,
>  √2 times as wide,
>  and one of four edges that go halfway down, to the equator.
>    Initial diagram:
>  
>            
>                 
>  [image]
>  
>  Improved diagram
>    (construction from cylinders is described later):
>  
>  [image]

The bottom view, for those interested, ...

> ...is a square,
>  the same as the top view but without the diagonal lines
>  because the bottom half is rounded.

This can be constructed by...

> ...beginning with this intersection of cylinders:
>  
>       
>  [image]
>  
>  That produces the following shape,
>  whose edges **below the equator** are then rounded off,
>  to remove those lines,
>  without affecting the orthogonal profiles or top view.
>  
>             
>  [image]

Comment: could you draw simple 3d of this?

Comment: I don't see how this works.

Comment: Okay, @matin, I found some helpful images

Comment: Please have another look, @greenturtle3141, I found some helpful images

Comment: Are you sure that those edges of the square can be rounded if the front and side views are perfect circles? I have a hard time imagining this. Maybe you could show a 3d image of it?

Comment: @elias, the profiles are produced by the "flat" portions of the intersection (original cylinder walls). The only place this comes close to a conflict with rounded edges below the equator is at the very bottom, where everything tapers to a point that vanishes infinitesimally. (The rough profile drawings at the top of this post will have to suffice as 3-D images of the result.)

Comment: I see no problem with this answer. The 45° should have a ratio of $1:\sqrt 2$, which is not too well-illustrated in your drawn image, though :-)

Comment: @humn To make the answer more convincing, maybe you can provide a proof sketch that there exists such a rounded-off construction? It is pretty clear that the two orthogonal middle circles (passing trough the crossing intersections) form perfect circles and, thus, the silhouettes will be perfect circles too. Removing the corners will not affect that property.

Comment: The diagram is more accurate and explanatory now, @Carl Löndahl, thank you for the feedback

Comment: You were right to suspect the smoothed corners, @elias, as they cause imperfection at all non-orthogonal angles. The rough diagram has been improved.

Comment: What software do you use to construct the 3d images?

Comment: The colorful 3-D images were found with a web search for "intersect cylinder," @suomynonA, and the line drawings were made by hand with mspaint, which is fairly easy to use and probably lurks for free on every Windows system. (Other often-better drawing programs (such as GIMP) are free to download on most other systems.)

Answer (score 4):

Sides could be either of two, or maybe even an infinite amount inbetween , depending where you put the point in the middle.
These two models are kinda low poly. So you have to imaginethe curvature a bit Here is a link to watch the second one online: [a360autodesk](https://a360.autodesk.com/viewer/#id/dXJuOmFkc2sub2JqZWN0czpvcy5vYmplY3Q6YTM2MHZpZXdlci90MTQ4ODE0MDQ3NDU4M18wNDQ0MzM0NDIyOTg0ODI2N18xNDg4MTQwNDc0NTgzLnN0bA?designtype=)

1. picture middle point to the top

[image]

2. picture middle point to the bottom

[image]

Comment: Could you maybe provide a link to an STL viewer so we can see it there? I'm having a hard time trying to figure out no. 2

Comment: Here is a Link [a360autodesk](https://a360.autodesk.com/viewer/#id/dXJuOmFkc2sub2JqZWN0czpvcy5vYmplY3Q6YTM2MHZpZXdlci90MTQ4ODE0MDQ3NDU4M18wNDQ0MzM0NDIyOTg0ODI2N18xNDg4MTQwNDc0NTgzLnN0bA?designtype=)

Comment: Thanks! Maybe edit it into the question for others to be able to see it too

Comment: What software do you use to construct the 3d images?

Comment: Cinema4d. Something similar should be possible with blender (free alternative)

Answer (score 3):

Second try, some kind of XBOX logo shaped cutout on top of a cylinder:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

A possible figure would be the following:

> Top view: 
> [image]
>  Front view: 
> [image]
>  Side view: 
> [image]
>  
> View the design [here](https://www.tinkercad.com/things/b0Cr8vPf5Jw-magic-figure). (But you won't be able to see the lines for some reason)

Comment: could you draw simple 3d of this?

Answer (score 1):

I made a quick 3D model on tinkercad which can be viewed [here](https://www.tinkercad.com/things/9HGOLbS7AQd)

It seems it is a cylinder, with a couple of rings going round it which form a cross on top. Here is the suspected side view:

[image]

I know that there aren't any lines which aren't visible from the top or front, but I'd argue that the rings are a single line, as a circle has a single side, so that these lines are in fact visible from the top.

Apart from that the top view is a square with a cross (imagine the black rings were flat):

[image]

And the front view is a circle:

[image]

Comment: It can't be a sphere, rings or no rings, if it looks like a square from the top.

Comment: @randal'thor sorry meant cylinder

Comment: Doesn't this have "lines which are not visible from the side or top view"?

Comment: @humn ah didn't see that. However it could be argued that the rings are single lines which are visible from the top